# Jackson: How to change specific fields key dynamically in serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson2

I am using Jackson for serialization and I'm struggling with changing field names dynamically. Here is my class:

```
public class Response<T> {

T data = null;
@JsonProperty(value="info") // No I18N
Information information = null;

public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public Information getInformation() {
    return information;
}
public void setInformation(Information information) {
    this.information = information;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}}
```

I have to change the field names dynamically based on the resource.
Does anyone know how to do this or if this is possible?